# Moodle By pass the registration Process

Tags: moodle

Trying to integrate Moodle into an existing website. I have the users sign into my website and I want user will jump to the course created on Moodle within the website, user doesn't have to re enter a username and password because already done on website.

I have already used the available plugin (Enrolment) that should bypass this screen but it isn't working. Not sure using a right plug-ins or right steps.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an authentication plugin

https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Authentication

And probably a Single Sign On (SSO) plugin

Moodle has OAuth2 built in

https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/OAuth_2_authentication

If your existing site uses SSO, then I would recommend downloading and installing this SSO plugin - SAML2

https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_saml2

Comment: Thanks @Russell England. We are trying with your steps and I will share the status soon.

Answer (score 0):

Look at User key authentication plugin
https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_userkey

Plugin generates one time login URL using mappingfield: email, login or user_id. Plugin can create/update moodle user.